# Input argument is a file or an either content to Perl

Tags: perl

I wrote a Perl script to convert from TEX format to JSON format.

Calling in the batch file:

```
 perl -w C:\test\support.pl TestingSample.tex
```

This is working fine now.

Perl script having two types of input from another program (might be any platform/technology) one is file (*TEX) or else content (*TEX file) *either this or that option*.

How can I receive the full content as the input to the Perl script?

Now my Perl script is:

```
 my $texfile = $ARGV[0]; my $texcnt = "";
 readFileinString($texfile, \$texcnt);
```

I am trying to update:

```
 perl -w C:/test/support.pl --input $texcnt" #Content is Input
```

I am receiving error message:

```
 The command line is too long.
```

Could someone please advice?

Comment: *"...in case if the file doesn't having the input file.."* what does that mean? Please clarify

Comment: Maybe try writing the string to a temp file? See e.g. [File::Temp](https://perldoc.perl.org/File/Temp.html)

Comment: @HåkonHægland: Question Updated.... Temp file doesn't support. Since programmatically I am receiving input file or content of the file.

Comment: @ssr1012 Do you want to pass an entire file’s contents as a command line argument? Why?! That’s just strange, and the error you’re getting is quite sane; the command line becomes too long. There’s a reason this is not a common thing. Sending contents via STDIN, however, is.

Comment: @Biffen: Yes I know that. But the full content only input for my script... And how can I receive the input content to the script?

Comment: @ssr1012 STDIN?

Comment: @Biffen: I am receiving the error message _The syntax of the command is in incorrect_.

Comment: @ssr1012 What would I do with that information?! I have no idea what command that is!

Comment: *"Temp file doesn't support..."* I was thinking you could write temp file after receiving the string. Then call `support.pl` with the name of the temp file

Comment: @HåkonHægland: Yes I can do... However Once I have received then only I can save the temp file. The problem is the tool can't receive the content as an input. That's the issue.

Comment: @ssr1012  *"...the tool can't receive the content as an input."* sorry if I misunderstood, but the tool (`support.pl`) can take a file name (as you show). Then why can't you give it the name of the temp file?

Answer (score 0):

First of all regarding the error you're getting:
Perl (or your shell) is complaining that your input argument is too long.

Parsing entire files as arguments to scripts is generally a bad idea anyway, for example quotation mark escaping etc. might not be handled and thus leave a wide open vulnarbility to **your entire system**!

So the solution to this is to modify your script so that it can take the file as an argument (if that isn't already the case) and if you really need to have an entire file's content parsed as an argument I'd really advise you to create a temporary file in `/tmp/` (if on Linux) or in your `%TEMP%` directory on Windows and parse the file the content into the file and after that give your `support.pl` script the new temp file as an argument.

Comment: Quoting is only an issue if you go through the shell. You can call programs directly (and pass arbitrary arguments) without going through the shell; at least this is the case on Unix. Windows is a different issue.

Comment: Actually the question is how to parse the content as an input in the perl script... **__you to create a temporary file in /tmp/__** this thing should be happened in the another program which doesn't happened.